# laravel adding URL to imploded data

Tags: php, laravel, implode

I want to know how can I have linked result for imploded data?

## Code

this code return my product category nested (I use this as breadcrumbs)

```
$category = $product->category;
if(!empty($category->category_id)){

    if(!empty($category->parent->category_id)){
    $category = implode(" > ", [$category->parent->parent->title,$category->parent->title,$category->title]);
    }else{
    $category = implode(" > ", [$category->parent->title,$category->title]);
    }

}else{
    $category = $product->category->title;
}
```

result of code above is like:

```
Notebook > HP > HP Pavilion > [I place product name here]
```

All I want is to add slugs in those category names `Notebook, Hp, Hp Pavilion`.

How can I do that?

## Update

`product model`

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

//just added
public function getBreadCrumb() {
    // assuming that each product must be in some category,if not, add an empty check before adding into this array 
    $crumbs = array(
        $this->category->getBreadCrumb(), // function in your `Category` model
        '<a href="' . $this->slug . '">' . $this->title . '</a>'
    );
    return implode(">", $crumbs);
 }
```

`category model`

```
public function categories()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
  }

  public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'category_id','id') ;
  }

  public function parent()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
  }

  public function isParent()
  {
      return !$this->category_id ? true : false; // if category_id is null => is a Parent Category
  }
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }


//just added
public function getBreadCrumb(){
        $crumbs = array();

        // handle parent
        if(!empty($this->parent)){
            $crumbs[] = $this->parent->getBreadCrumb();  
        }

        $crumbs[] = '<a href="' . $this->slug . '">' . $this->title . '</a>';
        return implode(">", $crumbs);
    }
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hi, your question is bit confusing in terms of what is actually required. Do you want to minimize this 4 line statement with a one line or do it in a more optimized way? Please explain.

Comment: @FarooqKhan hi thanks for asking, my code return my categories titles I just want add slug `<a></a>` tag to those returned titles. so when I print `Notebook` it has link.

Comment: If I were to implement this I'd use it as a helper method in respective models as `product->getBreadcrumb()` and '$category->getBreadcrumb()'. Each of these is a function in `Model` where you can format it as per your needs. Let me know if you need further explaination about this.

Comment: @FarooqKhan any way that can give me that result is fine by me, please share with me your solution if you may.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this can be ...

#### `Product` Model

Create a simple function

```
  public function getBreadCrumb() {
     // assuming that each product must be in some category,if not, add an empty check before adding into this array 
     $crumbs = array(
         $this->category->getBreadCrumb(), // function in your `Category` model
         '<a href="' . $this->product_url . '">' . $this->product_title . '</a>'
     );
     return implode(">", $crumbs);
  }
```

#### `Category` Model

```
  public function getBreadCrumb(){
      $crumbs = array();

      // handle parent
      if(!empty($this->parent)){
          $crumbs[] = $this->parent->getBreadCrumb();  
      }

      $crumbs[] = '<a href="' . $this->category_url . '">' . $this->category_title . '</a>'
      return implode(">", $crumbs);
  }
```

And now, where ever you need it, just call `$product->getBreadCrumb()` and it will get you all the trail along with categories

Comment: it returns `Call to a member function getBreadCrumb() on string` on `// handle parent
        if(!empty($this->parent)){
            $crumbs[] = $this->parent->getBreadCrumb();  
        }`

Comment: I assumed that `$category->parent` will be a `category` type object, but in your case it is a string. You must use parent_catgory object here instead of string

Comment: I didn't understand what you said! please wait i'll share my models with you

Comment: in my blade i said `{{$product->category->parent}}` got: `{"id":1,"title":"Notebook","description":null,"image":"category-1528762207.png","imageAlt":null,"image_header":"categoryheader-1528863834.jpg","image_header_alt":"header image","cheading":"Jual Notebook Murah dan bergaransi resmi","listed":"0","slug":"notebook","sort":"1","meta_description":null,"meta_tags":null,"status_id":1,"category_id":null,"created_at":"2018-06-12 14:10:07","updated_at":"2018-06-29 00:11:10"}`

Comment: updated my answer, call `parent` as function is the right way. Typo

Comment: now i'm getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getBreadCrumb()`

Comment: back to basic `Call to a member function getBreadCrumb() on string` /:)

Comment: Code seems to be right. Do you have any `attribute` named `parent` in your `Category` Model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183340/discussion-between-farooq-khan-and-mafortis).